# How to know which buttons are clicked in the other page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two page login.aspx and registration.aspx and in login.aspx the two buttons are

1)

```
<asp:Button ID="btnlogin" runat="server" Text="Log in" onclick="btnlogin_Click" >
</asp:Button>
```

2)

```
<asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btnlre_Click">
</asp:Button>
```

Now, when the registration.aspx page loads I want to know which buttons are clicked.
How can I know which button of login page is clicked at registration.aspx page tack load?

Comment: you mean, you want to know which `button` was clicked in the previous page?

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: The question is clear. *When page registration.aspx loaded, how do I know which button is clicked on the last page (which is always login.aspx)?*

Answer (score 1):

You can create session variable like this `Session["btnClicked"] = "value1 or value2"` (call this code when btn1 is clicked and store value "value1", and same with btn2, but with value "value2"), and the on registration.aspx, do something like this in `Page_Load`

```
if(Session["btnClicked"] != null)
{
    if(Session["btnClicked"] == "value1")
        *code for case 1*
    if(Session["btnClicked"] == "value2")
        *code for case 2*
    Session["btnClicked"] = null;
}
```

Or, alternatively, use `Server.Transfer("registration.aspx?btnClicked=1");` when btn1 is clicked and `Server.Transfer("registration.aspx?btnClicked=2");` when btn2 is clicked, and on registration.aspx in `Page_Load`, put

```
if (Request.QueryString["btnClicked"] != null)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["btnClicked"] == "1")
        *code for case 1*
    if (Request.QueryString["btnClicked"] == "2")
        *code for case 2*
}
```

**Edit (explanation):**
**`Session`**
The `Session` is stored on the server. It is used for storing data that is vonerable, or should not be seen anywhere else. So, for sake of your server performance, store only data like password, credit card number, phone number, username, mail in `Session`, and only when you need that information on multiple pages.

**`Request.QueryString`**
This function checks for variables in your header. In my answer, when using this method, you "stored variable", but just for the next page, in this case registration.aspx. Using this method, you are not using server's RAM memory to store variables. Instead, you're using client's web explorer to store variable name and variable value. Note that this data can easily be manipulated by anyone. I could just type in header something like "*your site*/registration.aspx?btnClick=23456", and youll have a problem. Look at google's header when searching for something. You see, google's engine won't be hurt even if you type your search in header instead of textbox that is intended for searching. So, when you know you can have (in this case) only two possible outcomes for registration.aspx, it's good to check:
1) is variable in header (Request.QueryString["btnClicked"] != null)
2) is variable anything else other than variables you need (Request.QueryString["btnClicked"] != 1 and Request.QueryString["btnClicked"] != 2)

In those cases, just send user back to login page. This way you saved server's RAM and got the result you wanted.